# Use SnackBar instance to show again & again

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

***Steps***

I am able to save SnackBar instance like this:

```
mSnackBar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.snack_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
```

And for the **1st** time it is shown pretty easily using this: `mSnackBar.show();`

***Problem***

But after I **clear** this Snack using this: `mSnackBar.dismiss()`

Its not shown again in *LOLLIPOP* devices,
where it is shown again (when required using `show()`) in *JELLYBEAN* emulator which is the **EXPECTED** behaviour.

***Question***

Please help me find what is wrong or missing in this process for *LOLLIPOP* devices ?

Comment: so in jellybean you dismiss and after that automatically is showing again or you make some actions to show?

Comment: Yes, I perform an action where `show()` is called again and snack is shown again in JB devices.. which is not true in LOLLIPOP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing the source code , i can see that the "dismissal of the snackbar" would nullify the currentSnackBar.

> Source Code - SnackBar

```
public void dismiss(Callback callback, int event) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (isCurrentSnackbarLocked(callback)) {
            cancelSnackbarLocked(mCurrentSnackbar, event);
        } else if (isNextSnackbarLocked(callback)) {
            cancelSnackbarLocked(mNextSnackbar, event);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Should be called when a Snackbar is no longer displayed. This is after any exit
 * animation has finished.
 */
public void onDismissed(Callback callback) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (isCurrentSnackbarLocked(callback)) {
            // If the callback is from a Snackbar currently show, remove it and show a new one
            mCurrentSnackbar = null;
            if (mNextSnackbar != null) {
                showNextSnackbarLocked();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when you do a show on the same instance this code will run

```
public void show(int duration, Callback callback) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (isCurrentSnackbarLocked(callback)) {
            // Means that the callback is already in the queue. We'll just update the duration
            mCurrentSnackbar.duration = duration;

            // If this is the Snackbar currently being shown, call re-schedule it's
            // timeout
            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(mCurrentSnackbar);
            scheduleTimeoutLocked(mCurrentSnackbar);
            return;
        } else if (isNextSnackbarLocked(callback)) {
            // We'll just update the duration
            mNextSnackbar.duration = duration;
        } else {
            // Else, we need to create a new record and queue it
            mNextSnackbar = new SnackbarRecord(duration, callback);
        }

        if (mCurrentSnackbar != null && cancelSnackbarLocked(mCurrentSnackbar,
                Snackbar.Callback.DISMISS_EVENT_CONSECUTIVE)) {
            // If we currently have a Snackbar, try and cancel it and wait in line
            return;
        } else {
            // Clear out the current snackbar
            mCurrentSnackbar = null;
            // Otherwise, just show it now
            showNextSnackbarLocked();
        }
    }
}
```

which won't show the snackbar if its null.

> Solution

You should not call dismiss on the SnackBar, it will auto hide by itself when the duration expires or an action button is clicked. Just call the show method again without calling dismiss in the first place to show the SnackBar again.

Comment: I dived into the code and checked that this nullify statement is called if callback is attached.. And I am not using any callback

Comment: If you'll look into the show() method , you will see that the callback is provided by the framework if you dont provide.

Comment: Thanks this is the correct solution and I made a workaround to dismiss and show again the SnackBars. A Point to note, this is also applicable when new snackbar replaces older one.. and for API 21+